# Critical points of system of 3 differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find critical points of system of 3 differential equations. 
I found Hessian which is $(k-x)^3 - 1 = 0$, where x is variable and $k$ is some constant. Now I try to find roots of this equation, but I got stuck. 
If I solve $(k-x)^3 = 1$, then I have $k-x = 1$ and hence  $x=k-1$, so I found only one root. I tried to solve it by using Cardan formula, but my solutions are not the same as Wolfram Alpha found. I do not know where I make mistake. :( Could you help me, please?
Thank you.

Comment: You have $$x=k-1, x = k +(-1)^{1/3}, x = k - (-1)^{2/3}$$ The last two are imaginary conjugates. Recall, you have $$(k-x)^3 = 1$$

Comment: @Moo could you write more steps, please?  I rewrote my formula as polynom of degree 3 and then I used formulas mentioned on this [page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula), but I have another roots. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$(k-x)^3 = 1$$

Expanding

$$k^3-3 k^2 x+3 k x^2-x^3-1 = 0$$

Factoring

$$(-1 + k - x) (1 + k + k^2 - x - 2 k x + x^2) = 0$$

The first expression give

$$x = k - 1$$

Can you now use the quadratic formula to find the other two (imaginary, complex conjugate roots)?

Another approach

$$(k-x)^3 = 1$$

Take the cube root of each side using complex numbers and arrive at the same result.

Comment: I used formula $(a^3 - b^3) = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$, so I found $(k-x-1)(x^2 - 2kx - x + k^2 + k +1) $. The first root is $k-x-1=0$ and hence $x_1 = k-1$. I will find the second and the third root from the second parentheses. I can rewrite it as $x^2 +(-2k-1)x +(k^2+k+1)=0$, so $x_2=k+ \frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $x_3=k+ \frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2}$....Your roorts are different. Where did i do mistake? I think I am right. :(

Comment: You result is correct, I just showed the same result in a different way.

Comment: I have one more question. I have
$x' = kx -y$ 
$y' = ky-z$
$z' = kz-1$
Can I find critical point as determinant of this matrix (equals to 0)?
\begin{matrix}
k- \lambda & -1 &0 \\
0 & k-\lambda & -1 \\
-1& 0 & k-\lambda
\end{matrix}
Are roots mentioned above my critical points? We did it in this way for f(x,y), but I am not sure, if there should be the first or second derivation in this matrix for f(x,y,z).

Comment: I have mistake, $z' = kz -x$.

Comment: I am confused, are you trying to find the critical points or the eigenvalues? That matrix looks like you are trying to find eigenvalues. Critical points are found by simultaneously solving the three equations. Maybe see: https://www.math.uci.edu/~ndonalds/math3d/nonlinear.pdf

Comment: We have to find critical points. We did it for f(x,y). We had the firs derivations, we gave it to the matrix and we subtracted $\lambda$ from the main diagonal. Then we did determinant of this matrix and we said that this determinant has to be equal to zero. Then we found roots and we said that they are critical points and we used this [picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment/150650) and we said, if it is stable or not. Now I try to do it for f(x,y,z) (it is our homework) but I am not sure, if I can do it in such way.

Comment: You typically find the critical points, the Jacobian matrix, then evaluate the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at each critical point. Perhaps this is being confused with a nonlinear function somehow? For the former, look at the example on page 1 of the pdf link.

Comment: Ok, so  am I right? I have to find determinant of matrix  mentioned above and this determinant is equal to 0.  Then I have to find roots and it is what I asked firstly. I found 3 roots (they are my critical points) - 2 are complex. Now I have to say, for which parameter it is stabile . But I found "table" for two eigenvalues and I am not sure, how it looks like for 3 eigenvalues.. It is stable only if all three eigenvalues are $>0$?

Comment: Mabye I will ask my teacher and if he will not answer, then I asked another question. :) Thank you very much for your help. :)